# Circuit analysis for bicolor LED

Tags: led, circuit-analysis

I am trying to control two LEDs in reverse parallel, using a signal `SIG`. `SIG` is an open collector signal, so it is either high impedance or pulled to ground. The schematic looks as follows:
[image: Circuit Diagram 1]

I am trying to calculate the resistor values such that the `SIG` can light one LED or the other, and passes 2mA of current given a 2V drop across the LEDs. This gives two states for the circuit to be in:

- `SIG` is high impedance state, so `R3` passes no current, and `D1` lights:
  [image: D1 lights]
- `SIG` is pulled to ground, and `D2` lights:
  [image: D2 lights]

Given VCC is 12V, is it possible to solve for resistor values such that the voltage and current drops through the LEDs hold true? After trying to set some values for a resistor and solving for the other values, I keep getting negative voltages or the currents don't add up. Is it possible that the currents through the diodes can't both be 2mA?

Comment: You could replace R3 with a short circuit which would simplify things.

Comment: What equations did you work out?

Comment: Looks like an academic  inefficient circuit question.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 your first hint that it’s purely a mathematical exercise should have been the equal Vf voltages. For different colours at the same current they should be different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works. Solved numerically. 
With R3=0, which is optimal for minimum wasted power, as suggested by Peter in a comment above.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCf8qu.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]
[image]

Comment: Yes 10mA bias with 2mA load. Hmmm

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75  Yes, and that’s the *optimal* solution with OP’s R3 =0.

Comment: Wasn’t that Peter Smith’s suggestion?

Comment: Yes, and it was a good one.

Answer (score 1):

If this is an actual application use a signal that can sink or source current (eg a microcontroller GPIO pin) - then you don't need R1 or R3.

R2 and R4 would be selected to provide the LED current you need. If you are running off 5V with red/green LED something in the region of 1K would work.

The LED can be turned off altogether by putting the GPIO pin into high-impedance (or configuring it to be an input).

A red/green LED can be made to glow orange by driving the input with a square wave at 50Hz or higher so that the red LED is on half the time and the green LED the other half.

Answer (score 0):

[image: switch open]

[image: Switch close]

Circuit Simulation.
Vled diferent

Comment: Can you explain what you've done and how this answers the question?